# tomcat7 - How to deploy spring boot war file

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I recreate a spring boot simple project "greetings", and when i run it On server, it work and i get JSON data in the browser like this:

localhost:9090/api/greetings

and it show:

[{"id":1,"text":"Hello world1"},{"id":2,"text":"Hello world2"}]

and i generate successfully the war file via console :

> ...\workspace-sts-3.8.0.RELEASE\demo>mvn clean install

and I have already set up tomcat7 on my ubuntu server 14.04 tls,

and throw the web manager I select the war file to deploy on the server:

but when tap the url to show all greetings for example, it doesn't show anything:

[error : the requested resource type is not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN1Gx.png)

so i check the error in the tomcat 7 catalina.out log:

> INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
>   Jul 28, 2016 7:38:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>   INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/javax.el-3.0.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
>   Jul 28, 2016 7:38:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>   INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   Jul 28, 2016 7:38:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>   INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.36.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class

But i did't understand what's the issue exactly,

this is my project structure :

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d831O.png)

and this is my java classes:

1/class DemoApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
      @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
        }
 }
```

2/class Greeting

```
public class Greeting {

    private BigInteger id;
    private String text;

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

3/class GreetingController

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static BigInteger nextId;
    private static Map<BigInteger, Greeting> greetingMap;

    private static Greeting save(Greeting greeting){
        if(greetingMap == null){
            greetingMap  = new HashMap<BigInteger, Greeting>();
            nextId = BigInteger.ONE;
        }


        //if update....
        if(greeting.getId() != null){
            Greeting oldGreeting = greetingMap.get(greeting.getId());
            if(oldGreeting == null){
                return null;
            }
            greetingMap.remove(greeting.getId());
            greetingMap.put(greeting.getId(), greeting);

            return greeting;
        }

        // if create....
        greeting.setId(nextId);
        nextId = nextId.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        greetingMap.put(greeting.getId(), greeting);

        return greeting;
    }


    static {
        Greeting g1 = new Greeting();
        g1.setText("Hello word");
        save(g1);

        Greeting g2 = new Greeting();
        g2.setText("Hello samsa");
        save(g2);   
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/greetings", 
            method=RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>> getGreetings(){

        Collection<Greeting> greetings = greetingMap.values();      
        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>>(greetings, HttpStatus.OK);


    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/greetings/{id}", 
            method=RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> getGreeting(@PathVariable("id") BigInteger id){
        Greeting greeting = greetingMap.get(id);
        if(greeting == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(greeting, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(greeting, HttpStatus.OK);

    }


    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/greetings", 
            method=RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> createGreeting(@RequestBody Greeting greeting){

        Greeting savedGreeting = save(greeting);
        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(savedGreeting, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }



    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/greetings/{id}", 
            method=RequestMethod.PUT, 
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> updateGreeting(@RequestBody Greeting greeting){

        Greeting updatedGreeting = save(greeting);
        if(updatedGreeting == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(updatedGreeting, HttpStatus.OK);

    }


    private static boolean delete(BigInteger id) {
          Greeting deletedGreeding = greetingMap.remove(id);
          if(deletedGreeding == null){
              return false;
          }
          return true;
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value="/api/greetings/{id}", 
            method=RequestMethod.DELETE, 
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> deletedGreeting(@PathVariable("id") BigInteger id, @RequestBody Greeting greeting){

        boolean deleted = delete(id);
        if(!deleted){
            return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

}
```

and this is the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> 

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Did you put a project .war to {tomcat-folder}/webapps?

Comment: yes i have put it manually in /webapps

Comment: I think you need to mark undertow as provided?

Comment: i will try it now ok

Comment: @Sam it's the same...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you did not set your context path on `application.properties` and therefore Tomcat is using the default path of the application name.

Add `server.contextPath=/` to the properties file to set the context path for the embedded tomcat and for the external tomcat add the *`context.xml`* with the below to your project to set the context path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/"/>
```

Comment: what mean exactly by specifying the contextPath, do you have proposition since I am new in spring projects

Comment: SpringBoot by default uses application.properties file for configuration. Simply adding the application.properties under the resources directory you will be able to override the default configuration by adding spring known properties. The server.contextPath=/ will change the context path of the embedded container but for the external tomcat server you will need to add the context.xml to main/webapp/META-INF/ folder. Inside the file add the following :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/"/>

Comment: I put all your proposition but still the same,
in the tomcat manager ui when I deploy the war file, I get this message:
"OK - Started application at context path /demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
does it mean something about the path..

Comment: Yeah seems like it is not deploying with the correct context path.

try the URL http://YOURTOMCAT:YOURPORT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/greetings to verify the application is working correctly.

Comment: i get this 404 page:

HTTP Status 404 - /demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/greetings

type Status report

message /demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/greetings

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: It is working perfectly on my side, will be possible to post your code on github so I can view the entire project?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,

I download a simple project from github and is working on both local server or when i deploy the war file on the real server tomcat7,

but here is the all previous project as you asked me before : https://github.com/hanigh/springboot